# Firestore - How to structure data the most efficient way?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures

I am a self-taught developer and currently I am working on a finance app and would like to ask you which way is more efficient to store my data in Firestore.

To say it in general, I have many users, but which also have many transactions and query them with a stream in real time. My question now is how it would be better to store this data and whether there are also advantages in terms of cost?

My structures to store this data would be like followed:

[image]

Which structure would you use, or is there even a better way to structure this data?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Answer (score 2):

as you are using Firestore so I think you want to optimize the Reads/Writes
so I would prefer the first one because you will have the user with its own transactions but the other one you will make a read for the user and another one for its own transactions but you can do it better by making both because you might need to get the transactions only so u can get it from transaction collection avoiding the additional quires to get each transaction from the Users collection

Answer (score -1):

for simplicity, and what i usually do is the "STRUCTURE 2". the structure 2 is what i usually use